# Spark - How to decompress Bz2 file to parquet file

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a parquet file which is compressed into bzip2, this is different than parquet file with bzip2 or snappy compression.

Could someone let me know how do I decompressed this file back to parquet file?

I tried following

```
spark.sparkContext.textFile("/mnt/shahgau/test/000000_0.bz2").saveAsHadoopFile("/mnt/shahgau/test/00000_0.parquet", "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat")
```

Error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: RDD element of type java.lang.String cannot be used
```

I tried reading it as parquet file, but then I am getting error

```
spark.read.parquet("/mnt/shahgau/test/000000_0.bz2").show()
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file:
```

Comment: Can you share how you compressed parquet file into bzip2 ? It seems to be working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Considering if you have used bzip2 yourself, I can use as below:
[image]

**%sh** Allows you to run shell code in your notebook.

**Compress .parquet**

```
%sh
bzip2 /dbfs/FileStore/user/adf/userdataOriginal.parquet
```

[image]

**Decompress back to parquet:**

```
%sh
bzip2 -d /dbfs/FileStore/user/adf/userdataOriginal.parquet.bz2
```

**Read parquet file:**

```
spark.read.parquet("dbfs:/FileStore/user/adf/userdataOriginal.parquet").show()
```

[image]

Comment: this would work only if files are stored in databricks local storage, not if that's stored in ADLS. I am talking about more than a petabyte of data, so moving back and forth wouldn't work.